# how can I paint the internal color (not font color) of a fontawesome icon to avoid transparency?

Tags: css

With this code I am putting an `icon` that has a `transparent` part in its `center`, I would like to paint it white.

[image]

With this code I am putting an icon that has a `transparent` part in its center, I would like to paint it white. Is there a way to paint it in a color so it doesn't look transparent?

```
  <body style="background:red">
      <i class="fas fa-times-circle fa-2x"></i>
  </body>
```

this is my live code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/BcLJQz59ACP5P5tY

Comment: I know how to change the color, `color: blue` but I don't know how to paint the center of the icon, it appears transparent

Comment: read the duplicate *fully* not only the title without clicking on the link ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif you are absolutely right, excuse me I thought you just closed my question, I had not seen that you put a link. lesson learned, you are very kind.